# Can you do sorting and grouping for the search results in solr using the solr config files?

Tags: search, solr, config

Assume the indexed fields includes:
product name
product type
product release date

Assume the solr request handler type is dismax.

Is it possible to sort and group the search results in solr search engine by using the solr config files, the schema.xml and the solrconfig.xml?

For example, when you search for spider man, if the search results came back with products of spider man DVDs and spider man comic books, and they are mixed one after another like this:
spiderman1, dvd
spiderman1, book
spiderman2, book
spiderman3, dvd
spiderman4, book

Is it possible to group the results, so that dvds are all next to each other and books are all next to each other by using the solr config files? If yes, can anyone give an example of how to do it?

Also is it possible to sort the result by putting the most recent released dvds and books show up on the top of the result by using the solr sonfig files? If yes, can anyone give an example of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Solr supports [Grouping](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) (also called field collapsing) which would allow you to group the results as per the product type.
This configuration can be added as a default to the request handler defination in the solrconfig.xml to be applied always.

```
<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <!-- Query settings -->
   <str name="defType">edismax</str>
   <str name="qf">
      text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
      title^10.0 description^5.0 keywords^5.0 author^2.0 resourcename^1.0
   </str>
   <str name="df">text</str>
   <str name="mm">100%</str>
   <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   <str name="rows">10</str>
   <str name="fl">*,score</str>

   <!-- Faceting defaults -->
   <str name="group">true</str>
   <str name="group.field">product_type</str>
    ...................

 </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

The group configuration as defined as defaults and can be overridden by passing as parameters.

There are two sort parameters are available which will allow you to sort the results for the groups and within the groups.

sort -

> How to sort the groups relative to each other. For example,
>   sort=popularity desc will cause the groups to be sorted according to
>   the **highest popularity** doc in each group. Defaults to "score desc".

Note the highest popularity, as the sort would depend on the max or the latest result from a Single document from the entire group.

group.sort -

> How to sort documents within a single group. Defaults to the same
>   value as the sort parameter.

Comment: If I add this requestHandler, what will happen to the requestHandler it was in use? I added <str name="group">true</str>
   <str name="group.field">product_type</str> to my requestHandler, it didn't return anything in the result.